# Spring boot Hikari connection leak

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, java-stream, hikaricp

I am using Spring boot hikariCP with Mysql, In a requirement to do operations in bulk where data is huge (100K per transaction). Faced OOM and DB connection leak while using Java-8 streaming. 
performance of the project is literally become slow , DB is growing in size. 
Please give you value-able suggestion to solve the problem.

Max number of concurrent users=200, hardware=cloud SQL (100GB) and database(Mysql 5.7)

Additional information:

Cloud :- GCP (google cloud platform)
OS:- centos-7
Mysql :-5.7
Machine Type :- DB-n1 (SSD) storage:- 100GB
Devices:- No additional

Comment: And you expect without code, configuration we are able to give you an answer? Connection leaks are generally a sign that you are doing things outside the scope of Spring and springs resource management (or in other words you are messing around with connections yourself). But as stated without code it is impossible to tell.

Comment: Additional information request. 
Which cloud and model?, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH MySQL client login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
F) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
G) SELECT name, count FROM information_schema.innodb_metrics ORDER BY name; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Cloud :- GCP (google cloud platform) OS:- centos-7 Mysql :-5.7 Machine Type :- DB-n1 (SSD) storage:- 100GB Devices:- No additional

Comment: Sharing hikariCP properties 0f project :- 
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout=900000
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=100
spring.datasource.hikari.minimum-idle=50
spring.jpa.hibernate.connection.provider_class=org.hibernate.hikaricp.internal.HikariCPConnectionProvider
spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties.cachePrepStmts=true
spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties.useServerPrepStmts=true
spring.datasource.hikari.max-lifetime=900000
org.hibernate.ConnectionReleaseMode=AFTER_TRANSACTION
spring.datasource.hikari.leak-detection-threshold=900000